# finding the index of list elements which are greater than 0

Tags: r

I have a list, "my_list", below:

```
$`2015-03-01 00:18:50`
integer(0)

$`2015-03-01 11:19:59`
[1] 4 6

$`2015-03-01 12:18:29`
[1] 12 13

$`2015-03-01 13:19:09`
[1] 1

$`2015-03-01 17:18:44`
integer(0)

$`2015-03-01 22:18:49`
integer(0)
```

I want to get the element index (not the subelement index) of the values greater than 0 (or where a list subelement is NOT empty). The output expected is a list that looks like:

```
2,2,3,3,4
```

I have gotten close with:

```
indices<-which(lapply(my_list,length)>0)
```

This piece of code however, only gives me the following and doesn't account for there being more than one subelement within a list element:

```
2,3,4
```

Does anyone know how to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: So, just to clarify, do you care about the values inside each list being greater than `0`, or just that the list is not totally empty `integer(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` along with a `seq_along` trick to bring in the indices of each element of the list.  Then, for each list element, generate a vector of matching indices.  Finally, `unlist` the entire list to obtain a single vector of matches.

```
x <- list(a=integer(0),b=c(4,6),c=c(12,13),d=c(1),e=integer(0),f=integer(0))

result <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) { rep(i, sum(x[[i]] > 0)) })

unlist(result)

[1] 2 2 3 3 4
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I hope this is what you have expected, Using `lengths` to calculate length of items in the list, then iterating every items of that list in rep command to get the final outcome:

```
lyst <- list(l1=integer(0), l2= c(1,2), l3=c(3,4), l4=character(0), l5=c(5,6,6))

lyst1 <- lengths(lyst)

unlist(lapply(1:length(lyst1), function(x)rep(x, lyst1[[x]])))
```

**Output:**

```
#> unlist(lapply(1:length(lyst1), function(x)rep(x, lyst1[[x]])))
#[1] 2 2 3 3 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat each numeric index by the respective length:

```
rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x))
#[1] 2 2 3 3 4
```

Using @Tim's `x` data.